# bootstrap 4 dropdown menu outside close

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using javascript to keep my dropdown toggle on a Bootstrap 4 website not closing when clicking inside the .dropdown element, but I'm having hard time getting it to work so it closes when i click outside the .dropdown element. Currently it doesn't close unless i click the toggle button again...

Any suggestions?

Here is the script

```
jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function (e) {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
jQuery('.dropdown-menu.keep-open').on('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

if(1) {
  $('body').attr('tabindex', '0');
}
else {
  alertify.confirm().set({'reverseButtons': true});
  alertify.prompt().set({'reverseButtons': true});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can add an `onclick: event.stopPropagation()` event on the `.dropdown-menu` to achieve what you want `<div class="dropdown-menu" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">`

P.S: to use jQuery you can use `$` instead of `jQuery`. If you cannot use it, you may have jQuery noConflict mode enabled somewhere in your code, see [jQuery noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro!, yes i tried this before but as i have another toggle dropdown within that element that doesn't work, but it works from the script i currently have.

Comment: Was able to get this working via second toggle element with your suggestions, so it's solved now. Thanks again bro!